# How do I clean data from a file and get it in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm new to python and trying to read /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/vdd_levels from a Linux system and get it into a dictionary. But how do I get rid of all the newlines, spaces and colons?

The returned data look something like this (The first number is unique):

```
1: 11111
2: 22222
3: 33333
```

I have tried in every way I can think of but it always end up in spaghetti.

Comment: You should rethink how your pseudonym will influence the chance of people taking your question seriously?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think very far when i typed in the name. Unfortunately I cannot change it in the next 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
import re
vdd_level_re = re.compile(r'(\d+)\:\s*(\d+)')

vdd_levels = {}
with open('/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/vdd_levels') as vdd_level_file:
    for vdd_level in vdd_level_file:
        level = vdd_level_re.match(vdd_level)
        if level:
            k,v = level.group(1,2)
            vdd_levels[k] = v
        else:
            print "line did not match expected format"
            print vdd_level
```

This will save k and v as strings. If you want to convert v to integer, change the last line to:

```
            vdd_levels[k] = int(v)
```

Comment: As a new python programmer I might be way off here, but I like the way this looks. Unfortunately all I get in return is an empty {}.

Comment: The library that is built up is in vdd_levels.

Comment: Printing it out gives me nothing. Maybe there is something different in the output I get from the file and what I have posted here. I cannot see what it is though.

Answer (score 3):

This takes your data in string `s` and puts it into a dictionary, `d`.

```
s = '1: 11111\n2: 22222\n3: 33333'    
d = dict([line.split(': ') for line in s.splitlines()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
s = '1: 11111\n2: 22222\n3: 33333'
d = {}
for e in s.split( '\n' ):
    k, v = e.split( ': ' )
    d[ k ] = v
print d
```

Comment: `s.split('\n')` is more easily written `s.splitlines()`.

Comment: Sorry, seems I missed the golf tag.